# How to separate integers and radicals from a term?

Tags: expression-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation, algebra

If I have a variable such as

```
r = 1 + Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[13]
```

how can I separate that into two separate variables with the rational and irrational parts? i.e.

```
a = 1
b = Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[13]
```

Comment: In this simple case you could use `{a, b} = {r[[1]], r[[2 ;;]]}` or `{aa, bb} = DeleteCases[r, #] & /@ {_Power, _Integer}`

Comment: Did any of the answers satisfied your need? There are **[things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. One weeks is enough wait. Participation is essential for the site, please do your part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{a, b} = Pick[r, Element[#, Rationals] & /@ List @@ r, #] & /@ {True, False}
```

> {1, Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[13]}

Comment: Just what I was looking for, a nice simple one-line solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In your example you could use `Select`:

```
r = 1 + Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[13];
a = Select[r, RootApproximant[#, 1] == # &]
b = Select[r, RootApproximant[#, 1] != # &]
```

The code above ignores symbolic terms leaving a warning. If `===` and `=!=` are used then the symbolic terms will be considered as irrational, but still with a warning.

However, there are infinitely many ways to write `r` as a sum of a rational and an irrational number. E.g. you could let `a = 0` and `b = r`.

Answer (score 2):

```
With[
  {
   r = 1 + Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[13]
   },
  {a, b} = {Select[r, NumberQ], Select[r, Not@*NumberQ]}
  ];

a
(* 1 *)

b
(* Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[13] *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Following function picks up manifestly rational and irrational parts of a given number. It ignores unknown numbers (such as the variable a below). OP's example:

```
Clear[rationalPartChooser];
rationalPartChooser = Function[a, {
  Pick[#, Element[#, Rationals] & /@ #], 
  Pick[#, ! Element[#, Rationals] & /@ #]
  } &[List @@ a]
];

1 + a + Sqrt[2] // rationalPartChooser
```

> {{1}, {Sqrt[2]}}